# How can i authenticate the model in rails admin based on the user's role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a Organization model and i want to authenticate it based on the role of the user i.e. **admin** and **superadmin**. When i am logged in as **admin** there should not be Organization model on the list and CRUD operation for it also should not work but when logged in as **superadmin** it should work fine.
Also i tried to hide the Organization model in rails admin based on user role but it is showing the following error:
[image]

I don't know much about the rails admin configuration so i might be wrong about the way i am trying to hide the model. So is there is any other way to do it and also a better solution to authenticate the model based on user role ??

**User.rb**

```rb
  enum role: [:admin, :superadmin]
```

Rails 6.0.1

rails_admin 2.0

Comment: your screenshot is irrelevant of the question. `current_user` is usually accessible only in Controller and View. 

What you are trying to do is 'Authorization' and is controlled by 'cancancan' gem in Rails Admin. Read [more](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Authorization) at Rails Admin's wiki

Comment: thanks for your concern but besides 'Authorization' i also want to hide the model based on user role and my screenshot refers to the error when i tried to do that. So if there's not access for  ```current_user``` how can i do that cause i think 'cancancan' gem will only help me to authorize or will it be helpful to work on  UI part while hiding the model based on role too??

Comment: for hiding UI part, cancancan provides `can?` method. Read more in [check abilities](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#check-abilities) section of [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rails_admin relies on cancancan for authorization, use that.